# nginx randomly stop - no error in logs - where could I look

Tags: nginx

I am facing a weird phenomenon - maybe you will have an idea.

I have nginx randomly stopping and I am not able to find a clue why this would happen.

I have checked :

```
/var/www/sites*/log/error.log
/var/log/nginx/error.log
/var/log/php/php7.0-fpm.log
```

Also ran `journalctl`but no sign of malfunctioning.

I have increased `pm.max_children`to 16 and limited the `pm.max_requests=500`in case there was faulty php code (but unlikely, as server is running a zero traffic wordpress and nextcloud install with minimal use)

It will stop on average twice a day. No specific time.

I am starting to run short of creative ideas.

Answer (score 1):

So, if anyone ever has a similar problem here is what was the problem:

Let's Encrypt was running a regular auto renewal process in the background - thus shutting down nginx properly (hence no trace of it in the logs) - and then crashing in the middle of its renewal due to some leftover of a faulty configuration - and nginx would therefore stayed down - but the problem wasn't with nginx.

This didn't show up in the logs because the server run a containerized debian distribution which has a known bug with its getty daemon, flooding the logs ( [ref](https://github.com/scaleway/image-debian/issues/81) )

Once I switched off the getty daemon, I could see the problem with letsencrypt.

So that's it.

Comment: I spent a long time trying to figure out what was going on. Your answer helped me find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50450860/nginx-randomly-stops-working-required-manual-restart (Which is basically the same issue, but caused by certbot)